# How to show number of unread message in layer xdk?

Tags: javascript

I am using layer xdk for chat in my web site. However I cannot find component that shows number of unread message from sender in `layer-conversation-list` . I have tried with `document.body.addEventListener('layer-message-notification', function(evt) {//statement}` But could not figure out how to do it.